# Setting transparency of background picture in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I am currently creating a short advertisement in Latex. I would like to include a pretty transparent background image for that.

Including the background image per se is not the problem, I have managed that one. However, when I try to change the transparency of it, nothing changes but I would like to have it almost entirely transparent.

This is my LaTex source:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pst-node,graphicx}

\definecolor{darkpowderblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.6}

\begin{document}

Advertisement title 

\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw [darkpowderblue, thick] 

([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle 

([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current page.south east); %---making a coloured box 

around ad




\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\node[opacity=0.6,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)

{\transparent{0.9}\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth,height=0.6\paperheight]

{Download}}; %--- Including the background picture

\end{tikzpicture}


Ad text bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

When I change opacity, nothing happens; when I change `\transparent{}`, nothing happens.

Does someone of you know why the transparency is not adjusted?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why do you have all the blank lines in your code?

Comment: If pst-node means that you are compiling with latex+dvips: the transparent package doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 7):

Remove all blank lines. Please only add blank lines when you know what it is doing.

`opacity` only is enough. Adding `transparent` or `background` may cause conflicts (?).

Compilable code, with `opacity=0.6`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{darkpowderblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.6}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw [darkpowderblue, thick] 
([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle 
([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current page.south east); %---making a coloured box 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[opacity=0.6,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
    \includegraphics[%
        width=0.9\paperwidth,%
        height=0.6\paperheight%
    ]{example-image-a}%
}; %--- Including the background picture
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow cool! It seems to work for you, but somehow my background looks the same when I set opacity to 0.6 and when I set it to 0.9.

I have also removed all blank lines as suggested. 

These two pictures look exactly the same and one has opacity= 0.6 and the other one has opacity=0.9

[link] (https://imgur.com/a/3AUOMiv)

Comment: @HelenaPokrivka Have you (1) removed `\transparent` and (2) removed the conflicting packages?

Comment: @HelenaPokrivka Please add your code to the question. Also the compiler you used

Comment: I am using TexStudio. 

And which code exactly do you mean?

The source code is 


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw [darkpowderblue, thick] ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current page.south east);
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[opacity=0.6,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[width=0.87\paperwidth,height=0.65\paperheight]{Download}};
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @HelenaPokrivka Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Which code do you mean?

Comment: @HelenaPokrivka The code that reproduces the problem. In a minimal form i.e. all unrelevant contents/packages are removed

Comment: @HelenaPokrivka I can never read a code in the comments, because comments don't allow line break, which is crucial in LaTeX. _Please_ add the code to the question