# How to overlap an image so that is behind text? (transparent image)

Tags: graphics, text

I was wondering if I can force an image to be behind the text; without affecting the text. Or the other way around which is to place the text on top of the image.

Here are the examples of my trials:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{Figures/Chapter_3/browserWindow}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I also tried `\begin{figure}[htb]`, and  `\begin{figure}[H]`. I tried following this suggestion but nothing happens so I use the regular way of creating a figure. notice that the middle of the figure is also transparent. Also as you can see from the size of the figure is not matching with the `\textwidth`. How to adjust this so that the lines of the window frame would match the `\textwidth`?

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter_3/browserWindow}
\end{figure}
```

Here is he demo and in case you want to work with the image here is a [link](https://ibb.co/wgNdg5Y).

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
        \includegraphics[%
            width=0.82\paperwidth,%
            height=0.43\paperheight%
        ]{Figures/Chapter_3/browserWindow}%
    }; %--- Including the background picture
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to adjust the position so that it can at the beginning of the chapter?

[image]

---

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @Marian G's answer, I was able to adjust this as I wanted. I simply used this:

```
\includegraphics[%
    width=1.15\textwidth,
    height=0.83\textwidth,
    align=t,
    smash=br,
    vshift=1cm,     % adjust the vertical position
    hshift=-1.5cm     % adjust the horizontal position
]{Figures/Chapter_3/browserWindow}%

Some text in the paragraph.

\vskip 0.2in %I had to use some space because the images was overlapping.

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth{Figures/Chapter_3/technology_icons}
    \caption{Technologies used : (a) HTML5, (b) CSS3, (c) JavaScript with external libraries} 
    \label{fig:htmlIcons}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485284/156344

Comment: If you wish to add a specific text on top of the image the following might be interesting: [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20792/134144) If this is more about a background like image, maybe the following might suit your needs: [How to use background image in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167719/134144)

Comment: Thanks @JouleV.

Comment: @JouleV, this works fine. a tiny issue tho. I tried working with the `\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw [darkpowderblue, thick] 
([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle 
([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current page.south east); %---making a coloured box ` but nothing changes.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou That is only to put a box in the page. You don't need it here.

Comment: I also tried `(current page.north)` but now its at the top. Again this is not where i want it positioned. I'm trying to work on this [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz)

Comment: So basically you just wanted to remove the white space at the top of your image.  \includegraphics has a [clip=true, trim=...] option for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following approach doesn't use `tikz` macros and can be of your interest. As far as I understand your claim, I will present a solution based on the package `graphbox` that enables to add some keys to the usual `\includegraphics`-command.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphbox}   % allows to add keys to \includegraphics
\usepackage{lipsum}     % only for testing purposes


\begin{document}

\section{My dummy title}
%-----------------------
\lipsum[1]


\section{Another title}
%-----------------------
\includegraphics
    [%
    width=\textwidth,
    align=t,
    smash=br,
%   hide,           % hides graphics (if required)
%   vshift=-1cm     % adjust the vertical position
    ]
    {example-image}%% add your graphics file
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: This works great thanks a lot for your answer. I updated the final solution to my question